# SQL - Drop exactly duplicate rows of records based on 2 columns as validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a database called Clients_Visits and I have found that there are so many duplicate records of a patricular patient based on their visit date and type of visit. I'm just wondering if somebody can help me eliminate/drop this records which are occupying spaces.

Sample Data:

**Clients_Visits:tbl**

```
RecID | Customer_No | DateOfVisit | VisitType
--------------------------------------------
01    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 1
02    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 1
03    | 1002        | 06/09/2010  | 2
04    | 1004        | 07/08/2008  | 2
05    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 3
```

**In my sample table data. I want to drop record RecID 01 or RecID 02 (But for the sake of example I'm dropping RecID 02**

```
RecID | Customer_No | DateOfVisit | VisitType
--------------------------------------------
 02    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 1
```

This records is under the same

- Customer_No(1001)
- DateOfVisit(01/05/2011)
- VisitType (1) 
  considering that it is only possible to have one kind of visit type per Date of visit.

Thanks in advance.

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

Sorry I think I have confused myself and some commentors.

Take note that the record below is not 3 duplicates considering that the VisitType of **RecID 05** is 3 Thus I need to Drop 1 Record only which either **RecID 01 or RecID 02** which is considered redundant based on their DateOfvisit and VisitType

```
RecID | Customer_No | DateOfVisit | VisitType
   --------------------------------------------
    01    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 1
    02    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 1
    05    | 1001        | 01/05/2011  | 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"occupying spaces"_ you should not care about space but consistency. If it's logically correct that one patient can have multiple visits per date, leave it as it is, don't delete inofrmations which could be important in future. Maybe you should change the type of the column to `datetime`.

Comment: The title says two columns but the question mentions three, by which columns do you want to determine duplicates?

Comment: What's the logic behind deleting VisitType = 1 compared to VisitType = 3? Those rows aren't duplicates, so they should be easy to remove. Using GROUP BY and HAVING

Comment: It is just that it is really redundant record. In our case it is not possible to have the same type of visit in the same date because the visit last whole day. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Just a remark: Of course you should *avoid* duplicate records on INSERT in the first place. Use a unique constraint (unique index) on the table's natural key (i.e. the columns that shall uniquely identify a record) and you cannot get duplicates at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Statement deletes all the records with identic Customer_No, DateOfVisit and VisitType.
The record with the lowest RecID stays in DB

```
DELETE
FROM Clients_Visits v1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT RecID 
              FROM Clients_Visits v2 
              WHERE v1.Customer_No=v2.Customer_No
                  AND v1.DateOfVisit=v2.DateOfVisit
                  AND v1.VisitType=v2.VisitType
                  AND v1.RecID>v2.RecID)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to keep the highest `recid`, there are several ways to do this.  One is to establish a `row_number` and delete accordingly:

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by customer_no, dateofvisit
                           order by recid desc) rn
    from yourtable
)
delete from cte
where rn != 1
```

Given your desired results, I don't think you want to add `visitType` to your partition.

---

Given your title, you'd actually want to do something like this, but it doesn't match your desired results as this would also remove recid 5:

```
with cte as (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by customer_no, dateofvisit) cnt
  from yourtable
  ) 
delete from cte where cnt != 1
```

Comment: +1 well spotted with the desired result. Although the text in a comment says differently

Answer (score 1):

So in case of duplicates you want to stay with the latest entry. That means we can delete a record when a duplicate with a higher rec id exists.

```
delete from clients_visits del 
where exists
(
  select *
  from clients_visits keep
  where keep.customer_no = del.customer_no
  and keep.dateofvisit = del.dateofvisit
  and keep.recid > del.recid
);
```

Comment: i think you have to include the `VisitType`

Comment: @niyou: Maybe yes, maybe no. According to the OP: "I want to drop records RecID 01 and 02" in the example. Supposedly because RecID 05 is considered a duplicate in spite of having another VisitType? The OP also says: "based on 2 columns as validation" in the title. (To consider only 01 and 02 duplicate and remove them *both* would be strange in my opinion. But well, maybe the OP was confused and "I want to drop records RecID 01 and 02" is plain wrong ;-)

Comment: Yeah Thorsten, I just confused myself. I should be dropping either RecID 01 or RecID 02. Thanks for commenting on that. The corrected text is already updated on top. Cheers...